# How to set custom font color of webgrid header?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, webgrid

I'm using webgrid in my mvc web apps with enabled sorting.

```
var grid = new WebGrid(
    source: Model,
    canPage: false,
    ajaxUpdateContainerId: "mainGrid"
    );
```

If property **canSort=true**(by default) then font color of header names is always blue (though I use css), but I want to change it for another.

How can i do it keeping enabled sorting?

My code:

View:

```
    @grid.GetHtml(
        columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column(header: "", columnName: "isChecked", canSort: false,
                format: @<text><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_selected" value="@item.index" /></text>),
            grid.Column(header: "Имя", columnName: "name", style: "name"),
            grid.Column(header: "Тип", columnName: "type", style: "type"),
            grid.Column(header: "Дата изменения", columnName: "date", style: "date"),
            grid.Column(header: "Размер", columnName: "size", style: "size")
            ),

       tableStyle: "grid_table",
       headerStyle: "header_table",
       rowStyle: "row_table",
       alternatingRowStyle: "alt-row_table"
   )
```

CSS:

```
.header_table
{
background-color: limegreen;
color: black;
padding-bottom: 4px;
padding-top: 4px;
}
```

All other styles normally working, but **.header_table color** when sorting enabled not working (when disabled it works).

Comment: Please can you explain what you mean when you say you want to change it for another?

Comment: I mean another color, i.e. not default

Comment: Do it with CSS?  This will probably be useful to you... https://forums.asp.net/t/2036473.aspx?Can+we+change+the+webgrid+column+header+color+when+canSort+true+ check the second link

Comment: I added some code. I cheked this link, but it doesnot help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you render your web grid in your view, specify CSS class names:

```
<div>
    @grid.GetHtml(
            tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
            headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
            footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
            alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
            selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
            rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
            mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
            columns:
            // ... more stuff here
</div>
```

We can now specify the CSS styles for the grid and get rid of the blue (I've assumed that the rendered blue is because the headers contain links (`<a>` tags), hence the second CSS declaration:

```
.webgrid-header { color: #FF0000; background-color: #00FF00; }
.webgrid-header a { color: #FF0000; }
```

More detailed explanation on this page: https://stick2basic.wordpress.com/2013/04/10/how-to-set-webgrid-style-in-mvc/

I hope this helps!

Comment: Great to hear.  I take it that you had to add a second CSS Line targetting the `a` tag?

Comment: Yes exactly! (I'm a little newbie in css actually)